# How to count() an element in an attribute which is not in the same lv as another?

Tags: xslt

I can't get my Xslt table working eventhough I've tried many ways to write these count() lines.

Look the code below before looking at my tries. 
I've tried : 
(1)

```
<xsl:for-each select="Trans/Episode/Section/Turn/tour">
<tr>
   <td><xsl:value-of select="count(motBDL[@lexeme='JE'])" /></td>
</tr>
</xsl:for-each>
```

(2)

```
<td><xsl:value-of select="count(motBDL[lexeme='JE'])" /></td>
```

(3)

```
<xsl:for-each select="Trans">
<td><xsl:value-of select="count(/Episode/Section/Turn/tour/motBDL[@lexeme='JE'])" /></td>
```

(4)`

same with (5;6;7;8)"()" instead of "[]"

XML =

```
   <!--The entire code is correct (just for you to understand what I am trying to extract)-->
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF8" standalone="yes"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Projet-Info.xsl"?>
    <!DOCTYPE Trans SYSTEM "trans-corpus.dtd">
    <Trans scribe="computer-name" audio_filename="Debat Hollande Sarkozy 1998" video_filename="" version="8" version_date="181221">
    <Speakers>
        <Speaker name="Nicolas Sarkozy" check="yes"/>
        <Speaker name="François Hollande" check="yes"/>
        <Speaker name="Journaliste" check="no"/>
        <Speaker name="Journaliste 2" check="no"/>
      </Speakers>
      <Episode>
        <Section type="report" startTime="0" endTime="1408.652">
            <Sync time="0.152"/>
            <Turn speaker="spk1" startTime="0.152" endTime="3.038">
            <tour nbmots="6" id="000000">
              <motBDL lexeme="POUR" phon="puʁ">pour</motBDL>
              <motBDL lexeme="MOI" phon="mwa">moi</motBDL>
              <motBDL lexeme="JE" phon="ʒə">je</motBDL>
              <motBDL lexeme="NE" phon="nə">ne</motBDL>
              <motBDL lexeme="SAVOIR" phon="save">savais</motBDL>
              <motBDL lexeme="PAS" phon="pa">pas</motBDL>
            </tour>
         </Turn>
        </Section>
      </Episode>
    </Trans>
```

XSL =

```
<!--Code b4 is correct-->
<table border="2" style="text-align: center;">
  <tr>
   <!--<th>nom</th>-->
   <th>je</th>
  </tr>
 <xsl:for-each select="Trans">
 <xsl:if test="not(@check='no')">
   <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="Speakers/Speaker/@name" /></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="count(Episode/Section/Turn/tour/motBDL[@lexeme='JE'])" /></td>
   </tr>
 </xsl:if>
 </xsl:for-each>
</table>
<!--Code after is correct-->
<!--I expect when I run my program on firefox to actually run.-->
```

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed. It looks like you have lost the opening `<Turn>` element when creating the question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I changed what I've changed in my program

Answer (score 0):

You have started your expression with a forward slash....

```
/Episode/Section/Turn/tour/motBDL[@lexeme='JE']
```

This means the xpath expression will be relative the the document node, and not relative to the node you are currently positioned on. You should do this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(Episode/Section/Turn/tour/motBDL[@lexeme='JE'])" />
```

You also have the same problem with this statement

```
<xsl:value-of select="/Speakers/Speaker/@nom" />
```

And this is also refering to an attribute that does not exist. If you meant to write `@name` here, do bear on mind that in XSLT 1.0, if you do `xsl:value-of` and select multiple nodes, then only the first will be output.

Also, note, you have two `?xml-stylesheet` directives in your XSLT. I am not sure this is allowed.....

Comment: First of all thank you ! 
It still doesn't work but I didn't understand the part with `xsl:value-of`    
Also, I have an example which works with 2 `?xml-stylesheet` directives.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the output you expect please? Thank you.

Comment: two  stylesheets is not a problem (as we have an example to help us, and it has 2)
But then my program still doesn't run in firefox, (I've changed it on my question so you have the 13 out of 76 lines which are the problem) why ? -> Can you re-search on my program (Thank you ;*)

Comment: It KIND OF works
Thank you a lot. I might be able to take it from here !
A very nice thanks to you !